# How to clear double quote marks in json?

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

I generated a json using `NSJSONSerialization`.This is my code:

```
    // parameters is `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?`   

    let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters!, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
    request.HTTPBody = json
```

But my server received this:

```
"{login:23232432434,mobile_captcha:,password:22e233434}"=>"[FILTERED]"
```

It seems server takes the whole json as a key and I think this because of that `"`.Maybe there is other reasons,please help me!

Comment: Double quotes are most certainly valid in Json, however what you have posted is most certainly not valid Jason. Instead of asking about how to remove double quotes, why not find out exactly what format the server is expecting, instead of guessing what you think it might be expecting, and supply that. Sure some  SO idiot might supply an answer about how to remove double quotes but then you'll have json content that is even more twatish than it already is.

Comment: The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y.

Answer (score 0):

Those aren’t brackets; they’re (double) quotes/quotation marks. In valid JSON, quotation marks inside strings must be escaped with \, e.g. "Hello \"World\"".

The Web service you’re using is returning invalid JSON.

http://jsonlint.com is a useful resource to validate JSON strings.